# Updating kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

I have this deployment.yaml for kubernetes

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: smart-flats
  labels:
    app: smart-flats
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: smart-flats
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    name: http
    
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: smart-flats
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: smart-flats
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: smart-flats
        image: sleezy/go-hello-world:<VERSION>
        env:
        - name: SECRETKEY
          value: "${CONFIG_SECRETKEY}"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

but when i try to push new version of app, kubectl get pods still show the first one and no updated version, what should i do? i need update pod everytime i push new version. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off `kind: Deployment` is recommended instead of `kind: ReplicationController`, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/) for details. Once you have updated the spec, you can update image version with `kubectl set image deployment smart-flats smart-flats=sleezy/go-hello-world:<new version>`. Your pods will automatic restart with the new image version.

Answer (score 0):

- A ReplicationController ensures that a specified number of pod replicas are running at any one time. They do not support a rolling update directly.In simpler terms they will just looking mainting a specified number of pods and will not be monitoring image versions of the pod.
- easier way to get the pod running with modified/new image , after pushing the change to replication controller just delete the existing/old pod. new pod will get created with new image.
  [or]
- as @gohm'c suggested deployment instead of replicaset or replicationcontroller will be a better option.